# Syncing music and playlists across multiple devices

Tags: windows, android, music, file-synchronization

I am looking for software that would allow me to sync music and playlists across multiple devices: two computers (both running Windows 10) and a smartphone (running Android).

Ideally the solution would be network-based for synchronizing between the two computers, but I do not mind having to physically transfer the music to the smartphone. I need to be able to listen to music on my phone even when there is no Internet connection (e.g. when using the subway), so a purely network-based approach for it wouldn't work.

So far I've been putting my music in a file storage cloud service, and using MusicBee to manage playlists and synchronize with phone. This works fine for the music files themselves, but unfortunately not for the playlists: MusicBee uses absolute file names. This means that whenever I make a change to a playlist, I must manually do it on the other computer, which is not ideal and prone to error.

So far I have not been able to find music management software that behaves well with cloud storage *and* is able to sync with an Android device correctly. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Android ES File Explorer + winamp maybe ? or a tool that creates playlists with your needs : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Playlist_file_formats

Comment: Great question, nearly identical to my problem. Does anyone have the answer? Would using Microsoft's Groove provide the solution? I'd like to store my music at one place (perhaps OneDrive) and have the same playlist on my desktop, laptops and phones. Thanks, Tom Sawyer